# Como pegar o value de inputs declarando o this de um elemento [jQuery]?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jQuery(function($){

    $('#upusuario').on('submit', function(){

        formulario  = $(this).serialize();
```

**Pergunta:** Como eu pegaria o input `senha` e `confirmasenha` deste formulário para compará-los, claro sem usar alguma coisa do tipo `var senha = $("#upusuario input[name=senha]")` visto que eu já recuperei os campos com `serialize`?

```
<input type="text" name="senha" class="form-control bott" required>
<input type="text" name="confirmasenha" class="form-control bott" required>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não é necessário usar `.serialize()`. É possível acessar diretamente partir do `this`, que no caso de formulários é um [`HTMLFormElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement).

Os campos podem ser acessados de 3 maneiras:

- atrávés da propriedade [*name*](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/name) do campo: `this.nome_do_campo`
- através da propriedade [`.elements`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements) por índice: `this.elements[0]`
- através da propriedade [`.elements`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements) por nome: `this.elements['nome_do_campo']`

Para acessar o valor, basta utilizar uma das opções acima para selecionar o campo e depois a propriedade `.value` para acessar o valor:

```js
$(function(){
  $('#upusuario').on('submit', function(e) {
    var resultado = $('#resultado');
    var senha1 = this.senha.value;
    var senha2 = this.confirmasenha.value;
    e.preventDefault(); // impede envio do formulário
    resultado.text(senha1 + ' ' + senha2);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="upusuario">
  <input type="text" name="senha" value="senha1" required/>
  <input type="text" name="confirmasenha" value="senha2" required/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
<pre id="resultado"></pre>
```

Comment: +1 por não ter criado um `elemento [jQuery]` apenas para pegar o valor de um input.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer por meio da função `split();` uma vez que a função `serialize();` retorna uma `String` com delimitador **&**.

**Veja o exemplo abaixo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
    var arr = $('form').serialize().replace(/password[1,2]=/g,'').split('&');
    if(arr[0] !== arr[1]) {
      $('div').text('Senha incorreta!');
    } else {
      $('div').text('Senha correta!');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  Password1: <input type="text" name="password1"><br>
  Password2: <input type="text" name="password2"><br>
</form>

<button>Serialize!</button>

<div></div>
```